# Conditionally use java or android classes

Tags: libgdx

I'm using bezier curves in my libgdx project. I was testing the desktop version using java.awt.geom with GeneralPath but when I went to test on android, it raised an error saying that I can't import java.awt. Android have corresponding classes for GeneralPath, Point2D etc so my question is how can I use those classes in their respectives environments?

Answer (score 2):

Make use of the Abstract Factory pattern and instantiate according to the current context.
Provide separate implementations of your logic in the Desktop and Android projects respectively and provide instantiation in your core project.

A brief example of this approach would be (it turned out to be rather extensive in the end):

Since your core project does not have access to the code in the Desktop or Android projects (this dependency points in the opposite direction), you would have to pass something as parameter to your `Game` constructor. (that will be then passed in as parameter to the `LwjglApplication` constructor on Desktop and to the `initialize()` method on Android.) For example, your initializers would like like this:

```
new LwjglApplication(new MyGame(new DesktopFactoriesCollection()), cfg);
```

on Desktop, and

```
initialize(new MyGame(new AndroidFactoriesCollection()), cfg);
```

on Android,
where `DesktopFactoriesCollection` and `AndroidFactoriesCollection` are concrete implementations of a collection of various factories you may need for different purposes (including that of running different code for your bezier curves logic on different platforms), when it comes to providing code specific to the platform you're expecting it to run on.

So, in fact, the `MyGame` constructor looks like this:

```
public MyGame(AbstractFactoriesCollection afs, Object...params) {
   // some init code
   afs.init();
   // some other init code
}
```

where `Object...params` is anything else you might need to provide here.

Each of the concrete implementations of the `AbstractFactoriesCollection` specified above implements a `init()` method, where it instantiates all the factories used in your project. Example of such an implementation:

```
public class AndroidFactoriesCollection extends AbstractFactoriesCollection {
   @Override
   public void init() {
      bezierCurvesLogicFactory = new AndroidBezierCurvesLogicFactory();
   }
}
```

where `bezierCurvesLogicFactory` is a protected field of the `BezierCurvesLogicFactory` type in the AbstractFactoriesCollection class.
Do the same for the Desktop project.

So, you should now have two new classes: one in the Desktop project, and the other one in the Android project respectively: `DesktopBezierCurvesLogicFactory` and `AndroidBezierCurvesLogicFactory`. Since the `bezierCurvesLogicFactory` object is of `BezierCurvesLogicFactory` type, this means you should have an abstract factory class for your bezier curves logic in the core project.

The `BezierCurvesLogicFactory` abstract factory class should have an abstract method `buildBezierLogic()` or something, that both of its concrete implementations should implement, and each of them should return that logic implementation that is found on the given platform:

```
public abstract class BezierCurvesLogicFactory {
   public abstract BezierCurvesLogic buildBezierLogic();
}
```

Furthermore, have an abstract class in the core project, for the bezier curves logic implementation itself.
Put platform specific code for each implementation in the Dekstop and Android projects respectively. For example:

```
public abstract class BezierCurvesLogic {
}

public class AndroidBezierCurvesLogic extends AbstractBezierCurvesLogic {
}

public class DesktopBezierCurvesLogic extends AbstractBezierCurvesLogic {
}
```

where `AndroidBezierCurvesLogic` is placed under the Android project and `DesktopBezierCurvesLogic` is placed under the Desktop project, respectively.

And ultimately, in your code in your core project, when you are instantiating the bezier curves logic, do this:

```
final BezierCurvesLogic logic = game.afs.bezierCurvesLogicFactory.buildBezierLogic();
```

you can store the `afs` (the `AbstractFactoriesCollection` object) as a public field in your `MyGame` class.

And that's it.

This is a lot of information, I was even thinking of writing an article on implementing the Abstract Factory pattern with libGDX on diifferent platforms :)

I hope this helps. If there is any confusion caused by anything written above, please let me know and I will try to clear that up.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest copying the source code from either the appropriate [Android classes](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/graphics/Path.java) or from [`java.awt` (OpenJDK)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/awt/geom/Point2D.java/) to your project.

Comment: openjdk is either gpl or copyrighted, no? So I can't use it